# GUI Builder for Python

Tags: python

I looking for a GUI Builder for python

i know it exist, can see it in this image background

[image]

Comment: Has been asked several times before. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+gui+designer

Answer (score 8):

It is [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) 3, a GUI Designer for [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org). It generates an XML file representing your GUI. You can load this GUI later using [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org).

Specifically, the screenshot is running a [Mac OS X port of Glade 3](http://glade3.darwinports.com/)

Answer (score 5):

That's glade, it actually produces XML, which can be used with the PyGTK library in python

Answer (score 4):

The GUI designer isn't "for" python, it's for [gtk+](http://gtk.org) and the associated language bindings known as [pygtk](http://www.pygtk.org/).

there are two gui editors available:

- http://glade.gnome.org/
- http://www.mono-project.com/Stetic

Comment: What about Qt Designer and PyQt?

Comment: both valid but OP was asking about what was visible in the linked screenshot, which shows gtk+.

Comment: Your answer is worded in such a way as to suggest that only two GUI editors currently exist.

Answer (score 2):

I use **PyQt** ([PyQt Homepage](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro/)); it is built on the QT Toolkit ([http://www.qtsoftware.com/](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro/)).

If you are deploying to Windows, it works well with the py2exe module ([py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)).

It's fairly straightforward to use, especially if you already have experience with the QT libraries.

Comment: You have suggested a GUI toolkit, not a GUI builder as OP requested.

Answer (score 2):

The one in the screenshot is Glade.

However, there are quite a few GUI-Builders for Python, as seen on http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

Comment: Specifically, the list starts at http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming#line-80.

Answer (score 1):

[Tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) is one of many GUI builders available for python. I prefer it.

Comment: yes, I overlooked that he wanted that specific gui builder. 

I'll leave the post for posterity.

Comment: Tkinter isn't GUI builder; It's a GUI library

Comment: There are at least two GUI builders _for_ Tkinter: PAGE and tk_happy.

Answer (score 1):

[Gazpacho](http://gazpacho.sicem.biz/) is almost a clone of Glade, but written in pure PyGTK. We (the [PIDA](http://pida.co.uk/) team) are currently refurbishing it.

Comment: Link is down. 2012 Jul 3, 10.40AM

Answer (score 1):

A python GUI builder is [boa-constructor](http://boa-constructor.sourceforge.net/), whcih uses the WxWidgets toolkit