# Where can I find a GUI designer for Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, glade

Does anyone know of any GUI designer for python like Glade but for windows?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64971/what-is-the-best-wysiwyg-gui-editor-for-python

Answer (score 13):

[Glade/Gtk+ for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gladewin32/) is exactly like Glade but for Windows.

Comment: I have just downloaded Glade but I suppose that I need to install it as a plugin for PyCharm in order to use it. However, only *.jar and *.zip files can be used as plugins but there seems not to be any such file in the Glade installation. So what should I do now?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using PyQt and the Qt-designer(WYSIWYG gui designer) for making cross platform gui apps.

Qt has even gone LGPL, making it even more attractive.

You can find PyQt at:
http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download

Comment: Until PyQt goes LGPL, it doesn't matter what license Qt has if you hate freedom and want to write non-GPL programs.

Comment: Doh, didn't think about that one =D

Answer (score 2):

http://wxformbuilder.org

Answer (score 2):

I use [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro/); it is built on the [QT Toolkit](http://qt.nokia.com/).

If you are deploying to Windows, it works well with the [py2exe module](http://www.py2exe.org/).

It's fairly straightforward to use, especially if you already have experience with the QT libraries.

**Note**: this was my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529498/gui-builder-for-python/529602#529602).

Answer (score 1):

I use [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

It deppends of the GUI toolkit you're using.

For wxPython, there is [boa-constructor](http://boa-constructor.sourceforge.net/). It's a Delphi-like IDE.