# How to interface Visual Studios 2010 with Python

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, python-2.7, ironpython

I am wanting to make an interface with some simple buttons and text fields. My problem is that I don't know how to make an Interface with Python. I want to have the ease of drag and drop like that of Visual Studios 2010. I know there is an extension that lets me use Python. Do I have to use another language to create the form? If I do how do I do it? If not then how is it done with the extension?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529498/gui-builder-for-python

Answer (score 0):

If you need the forms in ironpython then you may want to take a look at sharpdevelop studio here:

http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/download/